# How to setup a continuous integration project for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, continuous-integration, teamcity

Our main development project depends on the jQuery library. Originally, we used jQuery 1.3.2. Since then we have started using TeamCity for our CI.

Recently we decided to upgrade to jQuery version 1.10.2 and this decision has led to the question of whether or not it should be included as a 3rd party project in TeamCity.

Does anyone have any experience adding this as a TeamCity project? It would be easy enough to add but much of my concern is in how to handle the jQuery references in the main project so that the version can remain variable (i.e. decided at build time by TeamCity). Does anyone recommend renaming the jQuery library to a generic name with no version?

I've searched SO for questions related to this issue but have found nothing. Also searches on Google bring references to the actual jQuery project or other projects for jQuery integrations. For example:

- [teamcity+"jquery+project"](https://www.google.com/search?q=teamcity%20%22jquery%20project%22).
- [renaming jquery library without version](https://www.google.com/search?q=renaming%20jquery%20library%20without%20version)

Any other ideas on how to setup a continuous integration project for jQuery?

#### Update1

Right now our html pages include a script tag referencing the local jQuery file. When you download a jQuery version, the file includes the version number. So by including the version number in our script tag (because its part of the resource url) we have effectively hard-coded the version into multiple places throughout the project.

The current jQuery files are being checked in along-side our html. In moving to version 1.10.2 we have checked in a new set of jQuery files along side the 1.3.2 version files. Would it be better to remove the version from the jQuery file names so that all of our script tags scattered throughout the project would reference a generically named jQuery file and leave the actual version to be determined at build time?

Comment: Do you use Visual studio by any chance?

Comment: You mean you want to watch the jQuery project on Github and when changes are made, you want to build it?

Comment: We could watch the Git repo but at this point we have only been upgrading when we need a specific feature in a newer version. Whether the build is triggered based on a Git update or based on a manual update, we are still not sure how to implement the possibility of a dynamically changing jQuery version in our main project. I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: @AdarshShah I had hoped to allow for a more generic answer but in this case we are in fact using Visual Studio 2012 and ASP.net MVC 3.0. What we've tried so far was to extend the Url Helper with a jQuery method that abstracts the versioned jQuery url out of all our Views. I suppose we could rig something together to update the jQuery version in the web.config at build time and then the Url Helper extension would pull the version from there. I had hoped for a more generalized solution but if you have VS ideas I'd definitely consider them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having spent a lot of time in this area recently, I would recommend building a small project using Grunt, Bower and node.js. I know it might seem like a lot, but it's well worth it for automating builds of front end assets and integrating into CI.

Grunt is a Javascript task runner: http://gruntjs.com/
Bower is a front end package manager: http://bower.io/  (Like Nuget, but for front end)
Node.js is the language both Bower and Grunt use: http://nodejs.org/

Steps to get going:

1. Download and install node.js
2. Install grunt and grunt-cli in a folder. "npm install grunt", "npm install grunt-cli"
3. Install bower. "npm install bower"
4. Download bower package for jquery. "bower install jquery".
5. Write your own Gruntfile.js to build jquery, modify the filename if necessary and copy to appropriate location in project/on build server.

TeamCity has the following plugins for Grunt and node.js (which work great):

https://github.com/jonnyzzz/TeamCity.Node

Again, I know that this is a lot to learn and take in, but it has been awesome for CI where I'm at now.

Comment: It's definitely on the more complex side but I'm willing to take a closer look.